# Layout field values not updating on initial browser refresh after update from modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout, modal

I have a lightning component which is a modal being called from a button on the record view. You can update fields from this modal and save. After the save, the record is saving fine in the database, but when the page refreshes the fields on the page layout still have the old value. It takes a second manual refresh of the browser to see the updated value on the page layout.

Has anyone come across this and has a workaround? Different types of refreshing the page don't see to make a difference, and adding a timeout to possibly give the backend more time to save doesn't help either. It intermittently requires a second manual page refresh to see the update. Thanks!